# Enumerate valid values for mknod

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, devices, block-device

I have access to an embedded device which has a bunch of block/char files under /dev. However, this is not a satisfying description of the hardware, because since the firmware is shared with small changes across a range of different platforms, the devs just decided to create as many devices as possible under /dev, statically, so that the setup works on all of the systems.

Is there a way to know by other means the arguments to `mknod` that will create a valid block/char special file?